# About forKeyPath

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing, kvc

I am following [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/understanding-key-value-observing-coding/) to get to know KVC.
stated in that tutorial the following

```
[someObject.someProperty setText:@"This is a text"];

 Using KVC:

[self setValue:@"this is a text" 
forKeyPath:@"someObject.someProperty.text"]
```

my questions are:

1- when we used KVC, why did we use ".text" in forKeyPath?

2-does "forKeyPath" should always refer to the object we have or it can be just any text

Comment: Do you understand what properties are and how they work?

Comment: as far I researched, KVC is an approach by which one can access the properties of a class

Comment: Read this document clearly https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107-SW1

Comment: I didn't ask about KVC. To understand KVC you have to understand [properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW1).

Comment: Recommended tutorial: [Back To Basics: Intro to Object Oriented Programming](http://www.appcoda.com/objective-c-object-oriented-programming-intro/)

Answer (score 1):

The line of code from your tutorial:

```
[someObject.someProperty setText:@"This is a text"];
```

uses two different ways to access two different properties, as such it is a bit confusing.

Declaring a property, say `windowHeight`, declares two methods called the *getter*, which gets the property value, and the *setter*, which sets it. These methods are named `propertyName` and `setPropertyName` respectively, in our example `windowHeight` and `setWindowHeight`. Calling these methods is the original way in which properties where used. Your tutorial line written in this style is:

```
[[someObject someProperty] setText:@"This is a text"];
```

This calls the getter `someProperty` of `someObject` which returns another object, say `someOtherObject`, and then calls the setter `setText` of `someOtherObject`.

Later in the development of Objective-C *dot notation* was introduced as a shorthand for getters and setters. Using this notation the getter call `[someObject someProperty]` can be written as `someObject.someProperty`, while the setter call `[someObject setSomeProperty:someValue]` can be written as the assignment statement `someObject.someProperty = someValue`.

In any of the above dot expressions `someObject` is an expression which returns an object reference. It may be a simple variable reference; or it could be a more complex expression, *including* another dot expression, which returns an object reference.

Using dot notation your tutorial line is written:

```
someObject.someProperty.text = @"This is a text";
```

The parallels with the KVC *keypath* should now be apparent.

Your tutorial choose to mix'n'match original and dot notation styles in the same statement, probably resulting in your confusion and questions.

HTH